# Jupyter notebooks import pyshp results in 'No module named pyshp'

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I am fairly quite new to Python (and really any programming at all) but have been using Jupyter notebooks  for a course I am taking.

I need to use pyshp so I installed it using `pip install` and it seemed to be successful. However, when I tried to import it to my Jupyter notebook, I get `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyshp'`.

Based on other people's questions on this site I checked the following:

in terminal:

```
python --version
Python 3.6.5 :: Anaconda, Inc.
```

in jupyter notebooks:

```
in: import sys
 sys.version

out: '3.6.5 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Apr 26 2018, 08:42:37) \n[GCC     4.2.1 Compatible Clang 4.0.1 (tags/RELEASE_401/final)]'
```

in terminal:

```
$ pip list
pyshp                              1.2.12
```

I've spent quite a while reading other people's questions and the various answers but haven't been able to get it to work. Any suggestions?

Comment: try import shapefile.

Comment: D'oh. That works. So simple. Thank you. There's a lesson in there for me...

Comment: import shapefile is the correct import name for pyshp. See docs: https://github.com/GeospatialPython/pyshp. Don't worry... the naming is not that logical!

Comment: illogical is the nicest possible way to say it...

Answer (score 1):

Solution: read/remember the documentation. `Import shapefile` is correct, not `import pyshp`.